# Проблема с загрузкой файла через ajax

Tags: php, phalcon, yonacms

```
$this->request->isPost()
```

Ответ 1

```
   $this->request->hasFiles()
```

Ответ 1

```
$this->request->getUploadedFiles()
```

тут пусто

> в $_FILES  есть файл

Answer (score 1):

Что значит "пусто"? Эта переменная: `$this->request->getUploadedFiles()` хранит массив всех файлов. К отдельными файлами работаем так:

```
// Выводим имя и размер файла
foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file) {
    // Выводим детали
    echo $file->getName(), " ", $file -> getSize(), "\n";

    // Перемещаем в приложение
    $file -> moveTo('files/'.$file->getName());
}
```

Comment: вот $file тут вот и пусто, то есть там пустой объект

Comment: Напишите код, как вы это проверяете?

Comment: нашёл ошибку 
         $resize_x = 1000;
                    $image = new \Phalcon\Image\Adapter\GD($file->getTempName());

//                    if ($image->getWidth() > $resize_x) {
//                        $image->resize($resize_x);
//                    }
Если закомментить то срабатыват, не пойму почему, обрезает нормально, если просто формой отправлять.

Comment: Так, ну чисто логически, получается, что этим кодом ты очищаешь контейнер (переменную) в которой лежат файлы. Попробуй после обрезания явно файл вернуть на место. Фиг знает, больше мыслей пока нет.